# wxTimer Concurrency Issue

Tags: wxwidgets

I have one (though potentially several) wxTimer(s) that are attached to a wxGLCanvas in a wxFrame.  The timer can trigger a redraw of the canvas.

The main issue is deletion--when the frame closes, naturally the frame, and its canvas, dies.  It seems that, while the timer's drawing is occurring, the window closes.  The draw-method-in-progress is now operating on an object that doesn't exist anymore, so problems ensue.

The problem only sometimes occurs, which further supports this assessment.  In the canvas's destructor (I'm subclassing), I call timer->Stop() before I delete it.  This does not appear to help--presumably because a timing event might just have been issued?

My question is how to prevent this from happening.  What is the correct way to stop repeating timer events before destruction?

Comment: Are you using events or overriding Notify()?

Comment: Yes, am using events with Bind.  No, not overriding Notify().

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* would be that the frame closes AFTER the timer fires but before the drawing completes.  I suggest: adding a flag that is set when the timer fires and only cleared when the drawing completes.  The frame closing code should check this flag and only proceed if it is clear.

Comment: I don't think that will work.  The frame could close between the time the timer fires and the time the timer sets the flag.  Also, I've done some more testing: it seems that the frame closes and then the timer stopping/deleting code is called.  I'll be working on fixing that.

Comment: Not unless you place a call to Yield or sleep or something similar between the timer firing and the flag setting.

Comment: Yes, if I slept for a little longer than the event duration itself, there's a *pretty good* chance it wouldn't happen.  What if the event timing is very long, though?

Answer (score 0):

It seems very suspicious that this happens if events are used to handle the timer expiration because the frame should only be really destroyed once no more events are pending, this is one of the main reasons wxWidgets uses delayed destruction in the first place.

If you mean "I call `Destroy()`" but "I delete it", I really don't know how can this happen and, as always, it would be useful to try to reproduce the problem in a simple example and submit it to http://trac.wxwidgets.org/. If you do `delete frame` directly, then don't do this.

Comment: Actually, I never call frame->Destroy() myself.  I intercept the close command with an EVT_CLOSE event table entry.  In my callback, I delete my timer object (which calls timer->Stop(); and then timer->DeletePendingEvents();, before calling delete timer;).  The callback then calls wxFrame::OnCloseWindow(event);, which closes the frame.  I think what's happening is that the timer starts a callback, then is deleted, then the frame is deleted.  Even though the timer was stopped and the pending events removed, an event callback was *already running*.